# How was the Death Star going to destroy the rebel moon in the Battle of Yavin?

Tags: star-wars

Just before the Battle of Yavin, Vader says

> This will be a day long remembered. It has seen the end of Kenobi, it
>   will soon see the end of the Rebellion.

Now, just before Obi-Wan died, Death Star was used (against Alderaan). As [a reloading would take at least a day](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10757/931), how could they really destroy the rebel moon?

Comment: by waiting at least a day?

Comment: according to wookiepdia alderaan blowing up and the battle of yarvin could have been a few days

Comment: It could've easily taken over a day for the good and bad guys to get to Yavin after Obi-Wan's death. There's a lot of time skips in that movie they don't bother to give exact durations of.

Comment: Seriously? Someone notices a plot inconsistency and gets a -3?

Comment: Actually a very good question.  +1, and please don't reflexively downvote.

Comment: there is nothing canon that says it takes a day to recharge the Death Star though so it is only a plot inconsistency because of a book somebody wrote in 2007 that is also now officially non-canon (even holding EU status when it came out and thus not wholly official)

Comment: Related:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16131/how-long-in-universe-were-each-of-the-star-wars-movies  According to this answer, Owen and Beru died 35:3:5, a day or two after the Tantive was captured.  The battle of Yavin took place sometime later, possibly 35:3:9.  [Wookiepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Yavin#cite_note-Time-10) suggests that the Battle took place between 35:3:5 and 35:3:21.  So the time between Alderaan's destruction and the battle may have been anywhere from a day to 16 days.

Comment: The issue being that Vader himself states it's one and the same great day.

Comment: @Ghanima - Obi Wan died on the same day as the battle, but that doesn't mean that Alderaan was destroyed the same day.

Comment: @Ixrec No. Otherwise, Vader wouldn't have said that.

Comment: @WadCheber, right.

Comment: dont forget that after alderaan is destroyed the deathstar had to send scouts to dantooine. "Governor Tarkin: You're far too trusting. Dantooine is too remote to make an effective demonstration - but don't worry; we will deal with your rebel friends soon enough. " "Officer Cass: Our scout ships have reached Dantooine. "

Comment: @Ixrec sure it *could* have, but *did* it?  Kind of the point of the site is to ask such questions, is it not?

Comment: Maybe we're confusing an Alderaan day, Yavin day, and Earth day?

Comment: @DVK i think its because the only plot inconsistency comes from a non-canon source. so the whole question is based off of something that is real.

Comment: The quote is "This will be a day long remembered. It has seen the end of Kenobi, it will **soon** see the end of the Rebellion."

Comment: You are saying “*just before* Obi-Wan died, Death Star was used (against Alderaan)” without saying what *just before* means. As far as I remember, Alderaan was destroyed while Obi-Wan was still in Han Solo’s ship heading to Alderaan’s location and we don’t know how long the flight took from this point. Then, the ship was captured, Obi Wan disengaged the tractor beam, Han and Luke freed Leia. Quite a lot of things happened “just before Obi-Wan died” and *after* Alderaan was destroyed…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [the answer to the question you referenced](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10757/5184), and the question of [why the Death Star had to wait for a clear shot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10757/5184), I think you're focusing on the wrong details of the quote you refer to.

> After firing a blast, though, the Imperial engineers had to recharge the reactor, which took at least 24 standard hours. **Though the energy output of this blast could be scaled to fire at smaller targets such as capital ships, as was the case during the Rebel assault on the second Death Star,** the two major instances in which the superlaser was fired were at full power at planetary bodies.

We see during the Battle of Endor that the Death Star can fire more than twice in 24 hours, it just needs to be used at a lower setting. It's entirely possible that the Imperials didn't intend to use the Death Star at full output, and only enough to destroy the Rebel Base. This would explain why the Imperials needed to wait to get a clear shot.

This is backed up by the Death Star Tech's dialog during the battle as they approach. They first mention approaching the moon, but then start referring only to the base itself.

> DEATH STAR INTERCOM VOICE
>     Orbiting the planet at maximum velocity. The moon with the Rebel base will be in range in thirty minutes.

> VOICE (over speaker)
>    Rebel base, three minutes and closing

> DEATH STAR INTERCOM VOICE
>    Rebel base, one minute and closing.

> DEATH STAR INTERCOM VOICE
>     Rebel base, thirty seconds and closing.

> DEATH STAR INTERCOM VOICE
>     Rebel base, in range.
>
> TARKIN
>     You may fire when ready.

Comment: i was just thinking this on the way to work, they only need to blow up a base not the whole moon.

Comment: *"Still, if there were any Rebel pilots left **after the destruction of Yavin 4**, he [Tarkin] would make them pay for the damage."* - Star Wars: A New Hope: Official Novelisation

Comment: I've reluctantly downvoted. Although it's a *clever* answer, it's factually incorrect.

Comment: It's factually correct when examining the only content that is 100% undoubtedly canon - the movies.

Comment: And for all we know, once the laser was fully charged, he'd blow up the whole planet just for good measure, if only to wipe out any rebels attempting to escape.

Answer (score 10):

What are the facts?

1. Alderaan is destroyed by the Death Star.
2. The incomplete (though claimed to be fully operational) Death Star II is shown firing its primary weapon in rapid succession in the battle over Endor in RotJ.
3. Obi-Wan dies the same day as the Death Star participates in the battle of Yavin, according to Vader.
4. The Death Star has recharged and is capable of destroying the moon on which the rebel base is located.

What else do we know or suspect?

1. Right before Alderaan's destruction, Leia announces that the rebel base is on Dantooine.
2. The empire sends scouts to Dantooine to determine if this is the case.

> Governor Tarkin: You're far too trusting. Dantooine is too remote to make an effective demonstration - but don't worry; we will deal with your rebel friends soon enough.
>
> Officer Cass: Our scout ships have reached Dantooine.

3. Both Tarkin and the Rebels act as if they the moon is going to be destroyed when the Death Star is in range, and both have detailed schematics of the Death Star and should know its capabilities.

According to the movies, their is no plot inconsistencies here. Whether or not it takes time to recharge the primary weapon, and how long after Alderaan is destroyed before Luke arrives on the Death Star is inconsequential.

Now taking in the single source of now worthless expanded universe cannon, should it take the Death Star 24 hours to recharge the weapon to destroy a planet, then logically it is over 24 hours between the destruction of Alderaan and the battle of Yavin. This time line also matches up with other EU works which give the destruction of Alderaan and the battle of Yavin almost a 2 week window in which they happened.

Comment: On point #2, that wasn't the Death Star, it was the Death Star II. IT appears to be radically different (larger, for instance).

Comment: The Death Star II in the old EU continuity still had a long recharge time for destroying a planet (still 24 hours, IIRC), the recharge for a low-power starcruiser-destroying shot was much shorter; only 1 minute, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Alderaan was probably destroyed more than 24 hours before the planned destruction of Yavin IV.

1. Han Solo, et al. are *en route* to Alderaan when it is destroyed.
2. Some time later, they land, shoot up the place (rescue the princess, etc)
3. Obi-Wan (Ben) Kenobi is killed.
4. Han Solo, et al. fight the TIE Fighters, and escape to the Rebel Base

It is more than possible that the sequence of events here take more than 24 hours in-universe